# How to fill a string with ordered elements via LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, formatting

Say we have a class like:

```
   class SystemMember : IEquatable<SystemMember>
    {
        public int Id;
        public string Equation;

        public bool Equals(SystemMember other)
        {
            return other != null && (Id.Equals(other.Id));
        }
    }
```

in a `List<SystemMember> elements` on which we have done

```
elements = elements.Distinct().OrderBy(e => e.Id).ToList();
```

`IDs` can be `1, 2, 4, 6, 9` and its Ok.

And we want to fill a string structure like `{first (lovest N)}, {next N}, ... , {last N}` for all `IDs` we have in that list. How to do such thing with LINQ?

Comment: fill with SystemMember.Equation

Comment: Just to be sure: You ***do*** `override` the methods `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode()`, don't you? Because without `GetHashCode()` that `.Distinct()` call will not work!

Comment: Thay up in comments tyo post say that without `GetHashCode()` `.Distinct()` call will not work? In which interfgace is `GetHashCode()`? Will simple `IEquatable<T>` be not enought for `.Distinct()` to work?

Comment: Inside your class `SystemMember`, type `override` and space, then choose the method to override. The two methods are not in an interface but in your base class `object` (also known as `System.Object`). They are virtual and need an override in this case. Implement `Equals(object)` like so: `return Equals(obj as SystemMember);` Implement `GetHashCode()` like so: `return Id.GetHashCode();`. I can provide details in an answer if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly (*CSV of SystemMember.Equation for distinct IDs*), this should be what you want:

```
var equations = elements.Distinct().OrderBy(e => e.Id).Select(e => e.Equation);
var asString = string.Join(", ", equations);
```

Comment: Thay up in comments tyo post say that without `GetHashCode()` `.Distinct()` call will not work? In which interfgace is `GetHashCode()`? Will simple `IEquatable<T>` be not enought for `.Distinct()` to work?

Comment: `GetHashCode` is in `object` so your class (`SystemMember` in the example) needs to override it.